# Is there a SIP library for Windows Phone 7 yet?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, sip, voip

**Latest developments:**
Windows Phone 8 now officially includes support for [VoIP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206983(v=vs.105).aspx), but it's basically just an extension of the existing Push Notification architecture, meaning the API only facilitates notifying a phone of an incoming call and allows having a familiar call screen.

*There still isn't a SIP library (publicly) available, as far as I'm aware.*

**Original Question:**
I am currently in the process of designing (not implementing yet) a Windows Phone 7 application that our team thinks should use SIP (the VoIP standard). With the new Mango SDK, this should be possible, since sockets are now supported.

Here's the problem though: None of the team members (including me) have any experience whatsoever developing for .NET, and we're working in a pretty tight time frame already (less than two months for implementation, starting early next year), so developing a SIP library from scratch is not really an option.

**So, here's the question:** Is there a freely usable (either OSS or proprietary, like a Microsoft API) SIP library for Windows Phone 7 (Mango)?

Also, if you aren't aware of any such library, how do you judge the chances an inexperienced team such as mine could succeed in porting existing libraries such as [PJSIP](http://www.pjsip.org/) or [ReSIProcate](http://www.resiprocate.org/Main_Page)?

Or, finally, is there an easier route to using some sort of VoIP on Windows Phone 7? Doesn't necessarily have to be SIP, but a protocol with a readily modifiable server available is needed.

(Foot note: I'm new to Stackoverflow. It seems to make sense to me to ask these three questions together. If more experienced members disagree, I'll happily split this into three separate posts :) )

**Edit:**
I don't know how much use this will be for other SIP / VoIP projects, but my team decided to go with the [Silverlight Video / Voice conferencing Modules](http://silverlightvideochat.codeplex.com/) from [Socketcoder](http://www.socketcoder.com) - they implemented the G.711 codec in C# and created their own protocol to transfer it from client to server. Because we are inexperienced in both C# and network programming *and* have to meet a deadline, we decided to go with this and expand it for our purposes (distinct users, security features etc.) rather than try to wrap our heads around the SIP standard.

Comment: Microsoft spent 8.5 billion dollars on Skype.  Coming soon.

Comment: Very true. However, Skype does not have a library available that will let you build a custom VoIP application, much less one that complies with the SIP standard. I want to develop an app, not use one ;)

Comment: @T045T have you found the answer ?

Comment: @entropy We haven't, sadly. Basically, we moved the target platform to Windows Phone 8 which is much more welcoming to VoIP development and allows native code. A solution may have appeared in the mean time, but I don't know of any.

Answer (score 2):

Look at that http://sipsorcery.codeplex.com/

This is not WP7 library, but they have Silverlight version. So it could be converted for WP7.

Comment: Thanks! I actually stumbled upon sipsorcery lately, and we've been looking at it. From what they say about themselves, it looks like they're in it for learning about the protocol, not necessarily a working softphone, but there's definitely usable material in there :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know any native SIP windows api for managing RTP/SIP. Maybe you could try to make a native unmanaged dll and importing it on your C# program (i.e. you can write and compile your dll with c/c++ in unmanaged mode).
I think that osip and ortp library are quite easy to be used and you can implement a sip client with those.
These libraries will manage the protocols, you will need to manage the audio (DirectSound can easily make the job).

[libosip](http://www.gnu.org/software/osip/doc/html/)

[ortp](http://www.linphone.org/eng/documentation/dev/ortp.html)

note that in the osip main page there is declared support for Windows2K. I used succesfully this library on WinXP. Maybe you want to have a look to the differences between XP and Win7 before starting.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately, neither of those has anything to do with C#. I was asking about Windows Phone 7, not just Windows 7, and WP7 sadly does not allow unmanaged code, unless you're an OEM.

Answer (score 0):

WP8 now support VoIP development.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206983(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: It does, but as far as I know, there's still no ready-to-use SIP library. Thanks for the heads up.